# Android - Checkable Context Menu Not Working

Tags: android, contextmenu

Here is the preparation code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.language_menu, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.arabic);
    if (UtilityPreferenceManager.getSelectedLanguage() == UtilityPreferenceManager.LanguageArabic) {
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        menuItem.setChecked(false);
    }

    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.english);

    if (UtilityPreferenceManager.getSelectedLanguage() == UtilityPreferenceManager.LanguageEnglish) {
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        menuItem.setChecked(false);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    item.setChecked(true);
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.arabic:
            if (UtilityPreferenceManager.getSelectedLanguage() != UtilityPreferenceManager.LanguageArabic) UtilityPreferenceManager.changeLanguage(); 
            return true;

        case R.id.english:
            if (UtilityPreferenceManager.getSelectedLanguage() != UtilityPreferenceManager.LanguageEnglish) UtilityPreferenceManager.changeLanguage(); 
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here is the menu xml:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/arabic"
          android:title="@string/arabic" />

    <item android:id="@+id/english"
          android:title="@string/english" />

</group>
```

The problem is that the menu always appears with English selected. I am sure that the language preference is saved correctly in preferences. In fact, the if condition is working fine, but it seems there is something overriding the selected menu item after finishing `onCreateContextMenu`